# Can I reach to Couchbase Lite database using Sails.js on a same device

Tags: cordova, sails.js, waterline, couchbase-lite

I have a thought regarding using Sails.js and Couchbase Lite(CouchDB) on same Cordova(PhoneGap) project and device.

I think, a Sails application is dependent with a Node.js that provides to reach a database.
 If I try to reach a mobile database like Couchbase Lite then what should I do?
(Sails application and Couchbase Lite database will be on same mobile device)

Comment: There are [several CouchDB adapters out there for Sails](https://www.google.com/search?q=sails+couch+db&oq=sails+couch+db); the question is just what the connection string looks like for connecting to a local database on a device.

Comment: Thank you Scott. I could reach them. "I wonder if I do it what is happen? Where should located my node.js?" I guess I can reach CouchBase lite directly on the phone. And Couchbase Server Sync Gateway provides to synchronization between Couchbase lite (mobile phone) and Couchbase Server (node.js). I need to more read when I start develop this part. I hope this topic become a good guide with time. Have a nice day..